# Grep elements from array that exists in output

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

Is there any way to use grep to find only elements that exists in specific array?
For example :

```
my @IPS ={"10.20.30","12.13.14","30.40.50"};

my $cmd = `netstat -Aa | grep -c IPS[0] OR IPS[1] OR IPS[2]  `

print "$cmd";
```

I want cmd to return the number of IPS (only those found in the array) that exists in the output of netstat command.
I know I can use " | " or condition but assume that I do not know the number of elements in array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `@IPS` array does not contain what you think it contains. I think you probably wanted:

```
my @IPS = ("10.20.30","12.13.14","30.40.50");
```

And I'd write that as:

```
my @IPS = qw(10.20.30 12.13.14 30.40.50);
```

> I know I can use " | " or condition but assume that I do not know the number of elements in array

I don't think that matters at all.

```
# Need quotemeta() to escape the dots
my $IP_str = join '|', map { quotemeta $_ } @IPS;
my $IP_re  = qr/$IP_str/;

# Keep as much of the processing as possible in Perl-space
my @found = grep { /$IP_str/ } `netstat -Aa`;
say scalar @found;
```

An alternative to the regex, is to turn @IPS into a hash.

```
my %IP = map { $_ => 1 } @IPS;
my @found = grep { $IP{$_} } `netstat -Aa`;
say scalar @found;
```

**Update:** Actually, that last example doesn't work. You would need to extract the IP addresses from the `netstat` output before matching against the hash. but I've left it there in case it inspires anyone to expand it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer , I tried the alternative to the regex and the array contains nothing. in this case is it matter how I insert the IPS into IPS array? because I do it by using command :    my @IPS = `$cmd | tr " " "\n"`;  chomp @IPS

Comment: See my update. That alternative version doesn't work. It doesn't matter how the array is populated - but you need to be sure that the elements contain **only** the IP addresses. It's very easy, for example, to get newline characters included too - and that won't work.

Comment: You need to stop passing so much stuff on to external programs. Perl has its own perfectly useable `tr/.../.../` operator :-)

Comment: Thanks for the advice , I will try the first solution soon and approve if it works.

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty way to do this is by utilizing the `$"` variable in perl:

```
my @IPS =("10.20.30","12.13.14","30.40.50");
local $"='|';
my $cmd = `netstat -Aa | grep '@IPS' | wc -l`
print "$cmd";
```

The idea is that `$"` controls how an array variable is appears when interpolated inside some quotes. So by saying `$"='|'` we cause the `@IPS` array to be interpolated as a concatenation of its elements separated by `|`. **Note**: you should only use this if you trust of the source of `@IPS` e.g. if you type it yourself in the code. If it comes from an untrusted external source, the above trick might be dangerous.

**Edit**: If `@IPS` does come from an untrusted source, you can validate it first like so

```
/^[\d.]+$/ or die "Invalid IP address" for @IPS;
```

Comment: Hi redneb , this is a very nice trick I didn't know about.  But this is not working for me , I get the value 0 when trying to do this although there are IPS in the output. are you sure about this line " `netstat -Aa | grep '@IPS' | wc -l`"?

Comment: Well , I do not type it myself , I take it from external source and this is why I won't be able to know the number of IPS in the array.  any other way you know to do this?

Comment: Thanks , I will try this.